# Comparing Active Cell Address To Contents of Array

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to loop through the values in a given range and write to an array the address of any cell that matches some criteria (for demo purposes, I am just looking for cells whose value is "somevalue").  I then want to take a second loop through the same range and compare the address of the active cell to the list of addresses written to the array.  If there is a match then I want to merge the active cell with the 2 cells below it.  That's it.  Simplified code is below.

The code works fine and is recording the correct addresses to the array.  But at the top of the second loop at this line "If cSched.Address = aBands(x, 1) Then", I am getting the following error: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.  All suggestions appreciated!

```
Sub stackoverflowtest2()

Dim shtSched As Worksheet 'the tab where schedule blocks will be created
Dim rSched As Range 'range of schedule
Dim cSched As Range 'a single cell on Schedule tab
Dim aBands As Variant 'array containing addresses of band locations on schedule
Dim BandCounter As Integer 'counter for number of bands written
Dim x As Integer 'counter
Dim msg As String 'for testing

'Setup
    Set shtSched = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rSched = Range(shtSched.Range("Start"), shtSched.Range("Start").Offset(122, 6))

'Loop 1: work through cells, record address for matches
    BandCounter = 1
    For Each cSched In rSched
        If cSched.Value = "somevalue" Then
            ReDim aBands(1 To BandCounter, 1)
            aBands(BandCounter, 1) = cSched.Address
            msg = msg & aBands(BandCounter, 1) & vbNewLine 'for testing
            BandCounter = BandCounter + 1
        End If
    Next

'Show all matching addresses, for testing
    MsgBox msg

'Loop 2: work through cells 2nd time, if address is in array then merge cells
    For Each cSched In rSched
        For x = 1 To BandCounter
            If cSched.Address = aBands(x, 1) Then
                MsgBox "We have a match!" 'for testing
                Range(cSched, cSched.Offset(2, 0)).MergeCells = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using `ReDim` without `Preserve` inside your loop - that will erase the contents of the array. Is that your intent?

Comment: Beside `braX`‘s comment, why not merge cells in the Loop 1?

Comment: `BandCounter` will always end up as `{number of matches} + 1`

Comment: @braX, thanks for pointing that out.  It is definitely NOT my intent to erase the array contents.  The odd thing is that the "MsgBox msg" line results in a list of all entries written to the array, so at least through that line, the array maintained all entries despite having been ReDimmed 4 times.  I also tried changing the ReDim line to "ReDim Preserve aBands(1 To BandCounter, 1)", but that resulted in "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome, the reason I am using a second loop is that if I merge the cells in loop one, it is no longer possible to evaluate the merged cells in the loop.  So if the loop gets to cell B3 and then merges B3:B5, it will effectively evaluate B3 two more times instead of evaluating B4 and B5.

Comment: @gurs It can be done w/o twice iterating  cells. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: I don't need the array any more thanks to the accepted solution, but if helpful to anyone, I did resolve the issues related to my initial code thanks to the lead of @braX. First, with a 1-dimension array, it is better to ReDim as variantarray(x) rather than variantarray(x, 1). Second, the ReDim Preserve was failing because I was using it before there was any data in the array. Instead, I needed to use "If BandCounter = 1 Then ReDim aBands(1 to BandCounter) Else ReDim Preserve aBands(1 To BandCounter)". With those mods, my solution works, but the accepted solution is cleaner and better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using nested For loops to avoid iterating cells twice.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim rCol, i, rSched As Range
    Set rSched = Range("B10:H20")
    For Each rCol In rSched.Columns
        For i = 1 To rCol.Cells.Count
            If rCol.Cells(i).Value = "somevalue" Then
                rCol.Cells(i).Resize(3, 1).MergeCells = True
                i = i + 2
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: My original question was about how to make my workaround function, but you actually solved the underlying problem that I hadn't even asked about, making my workaround unnecessary!  Thanks a million.  This works like a charm.